# Vuforia for Hololens

Tags: tracking, vuforia, object-recognition, hololens

I was wondering if someone else tried developing a hololens application using vuforia. Specifically, using vuforia's capacity to recognize and track objects.

I tried and it seems like it's working. I was just not sure about the result I got from the Debug.Log that print the name of the tracked object.
I tried putting two trackable targets millimeters away from each other and pointed my Gaze towards the distance between the objects(hoping it takes both).
Some how the output window gave me this.

[image]

It seems like I was able to track both targets but I want to know if I tracked two different objects at the same time.
I have this doubt because at some point, eventhough the hololens was in the same position as before, the output started to change and started printing only one of the two objects(the one in the right). 
I think of this as a problem caused  by hololens' small camera window or by hololens limited hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the vuforiaconfiguration you should be able to set the maximum simultaneous amount of objects your app can track. You need to make sure it is set to more than 1.
[image: Vuforiaconfiguration in Unity]

In the image above you see how you can set the maximum amount of tracked images in unity.

If you are not using unity you'll have to access the vuforiaconfiguration in another way and set the maximum simultaneous amount of tracked object there.

From code you can do it in c# like this:

VuforiaConfiguration.Instance.Vuforia.MaxSimultaneousImageTargets = 2;

Comment: Thanks! 
Are you developing Hololens apps with Vuforia too? :)

Comment: I have been busy using Vuforia vumarks to identify the location of a real world object, and using the vumark id to display data from a database.

Comment: Ey man, Was reading this but maybe @DarthCoder you should remove your license key for your own good :O